# Laravel multiple delete

Tags: php, laravel

I try to add multiple select to my app and delete data's at once, but they won't delete from database.

## Codes

`controller`

```
public function multipledel(Request $request){
  $deli = $request->input('productsfordel');
  $product = Product::whereIn('id', $deli);
  $product->delete();
  return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('success', 'Selected products are successfully deleted.');
}
```

`route`

```
  Route::post('delmultipleproducts', 'ProductController@multipledel')->name('delmultipleproducts');
```

`blade`

```
//multiple delete form starts before table begin
{!! Form::open(['method' => 'Post', 'route' => ['delmultipleproducts'] ]) !!}

//delete button
<button name="bulk_delete" id="bulk_delete" data-toggle="tooltip" data-placement="top" title="Delete Selected" class="btn btn-xs btn-theme04" type="submit"><i class="fa fa-trash-o"></i></button>   

<thead>
//table headears
</thead>
<tbody>
@foreach($products as $product)
<tr>
  //my checkbox's
  <td>
    <input type="checkbox" name="productsfordel[]" class="checkboxes" value="{{ $product->id }}" />
  </td>

// my multiple delete form closes here
{!! Form::close() !!}

//rest of the table...
```

## Issues

1. I get several kind of errors!

first

> Invalid argument supplied for foreach()

second

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or
>   update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

third

It return my success session and says `Selected products are successfully deleted.` but they're not.

#### opinion

I think the errors i get refers to my products attached data where i have like code below in my ordinary delete method `one by one`

```
public function destroy($id)
    {
      $product = Product::findOrFail($id);
      $product->suboptions()->detach();
      $product->subspecifications()->detach();
      if(!empty($product->imageOne)){
        Storage::delete($product->imageOne);
      }
      if(!empty($product->imageTwo)){
        Storage::delete($product->imageTwo);
      }
      $product->delete();
      return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('success','Product successfully deleted');
    }
```

As you can see I have several conditions and synced data to each one of my products but in my multiple delete method i don't have them, however I tried to include them as well but it gave me error on `$product = Product::whereIn('id', $deli);` not sure maybe i need to array my `$deli` somehow?

any idea?

## UPDATE

I realize that nothing will send to my controller, when i tried `dd($deli);` i got null instead of `id` of selected products.

Comment: I think the problem is on your blade file can you paste the entire code of your blade file?

Answer (score 0):

Eloquent `whereIn` does require you to pass an array of values, that is why you are getting a `foreach` notice.

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1451 Cannot delete or update a parent row: a foreign key constraint fails

You are getting this, just because your foreign key doesn't have an `ON DELETE` behaviour, so you should delete child (referencing) records (models) manually first.

Comment: i think issue is from somewhere else, when i try `dd($deli);` i get null instead of id of selected products

Comment: still returns null

Comment: what about $request->all()?

Comment: and what is the version of laravel you are using?

Comment: @jay result of all `array:2 [▼
  "bulk_delete" => null
  "_token" => "bvQtN9mINCVTsext677DICUWV6fXEMO65k8fl8e4"
]` version 5.5

Answer (score 0):

When it comes to multiple delete in once you can simply do

```
Product::destroy($request->get('productsfordel'));
return redirect()->route('products.index')->with('success', 'Selected products are successfully deleted.');
```